# Find outdated/updatable pip packages

Tags: python, package-management, pip

pip freeze shows me the packages installed, but how do I check against pypi which ones are outdated?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

Since version 1.3, pip features a new command:

```
$ pip list --outdated
requests (Current: 1.1.0 Latest: 1.2.0)
```

See [this post](http://blog.dbrgn.ch/2013/4/26/pip-list-outdated/) for more information.

Answer (score 14):

Thing is, **I never upgrade all packages**. I upgrade only what I need, **because projects may break**.

Because there was no easy way to upgrade package by package and update the requirements.txt file, I wrote [**pip-upgrader**](https://github.com/simion/pip-upgrader) which **also updates the versions in your `requirements.txt` file** for the packages chosen (or all packages).

**Installation**

```
pip install pip-upgrader
```

**Usage**

Activate your virtualenv (important, because it will also install the new versions of upgraded packages in the current virtualenv).

`cd` into your project directory, then run:

```
pip-upgrade
```

**Advanced usage**

If the requirements are placed in a non-standard location, send them as arguments:

```
pip-upgrade path/to/requirements.txt
```

If you already know what package you want to upgrade, simply send them as arguments:

```
pip-upgrade -p django -p celery -p dateutil
```

If you need to upgrade to  pre-release / post-release version, add `--prerelease` argument to your command.

Full disclosure: I wrote this package.

Answer (score 10):

#### Simple output:

```
pip list --outdated
```

[image]

See also docs on [`pip list` `--outdated` option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_list/#cmdoption-o).

#### Pretty output:

```
pip install pip-check
pip-check
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use this pip fork:

https://github.com/dgladkov/pip

Which does exactly what you want using this command:

```
$ pip list --outdated
```

Comment: lol, thanks dsa. We both already commented on the fork before :)

Comment: Unmaintained project

Comment: Unmaintained 9-year-old fork. Avoid.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps pip-tools, available at https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools, might help you achieve what you want?

An example from the README:

```
$ pip-review --interactive
requests==0.14.0 available (you have 0.13.2)
Upgrade now? [Y]es, [N]o, [A]ll, [Q]uit y
...
redis==2.6.2 available (you have 2.4.9)
Upgrade now? [Y]es, [N]o, [A]ll, [Q]uit n
rq==0.3.2 available (you have 0.3.0)
Upgrade now? [Y]es, [N]o, [A]ll, [Q]uit y
...
```

Comment: It seems this package has now moved to https://github.com/jgonggrijp/pip-review

Answer (score 2):

```bash
pip list --outdated | gawk -F ' ' 'NR>2{print$1}' | xargs pip install --upgrade
```

handy way to update all outdate package without install any extra package

```bash
alias pip-update='pip list --outdated | gawk -F ' ' 'NR>2{print$1}' | xargs pip install --upgrade'
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to `pip list --outdated` but updates a `requirements.txt` file:

`pur -r requirements.txt`

PyPi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pur

GitHub: https://github.com/alanhamlett/pip-update-requirements

Answer (score 0):

*Or you can*

```
pip list --o
```

*List installed packages, including editables. [pip list](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_list/)*